# How can I reliably de-duplicate requests in message queues?

Tags: duplicates, rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker

I have a scraper-crawler structure in mind which'd crawl "related" blogs based on their posts' metadata (tags, word occurrence, etc.), making post-fetch requests is expensive, making blog-index requests is "cheap".

To continuously crawl and update blogs, I start from a "seed" blog (either determined manually or by ranking) and then "pulse" it offline by going through internal database items to rank top-level related blogs, then rank their related blogs, perform staleness checks, perform completeness checks, etc, etc.

This is what I'm going to call a "source", this source creates a long list of blogs to be checked (after cutting off on (lets say) a thousand, and then rank them to grab the top 100), this can be de-duplicated within the sourcing process.

These submit this long list of blogs to be indexed to a queue, consumer-workers take from this queue and perform the indexing on those blogs, which places the results (of first pagination) on a queue, consumer-workers on that queue check the results (post IDs) with the database, and fires off another pagination request if *all* post IDs weren't found in the database, and fires post-fetch requests on those posts that weren't found in the database.

These requests end up on another queue, with which they'll be fetched by a big cluster of workers who perform the rate-limited/expensive post-fetch requests on this queue.

This is all just with 1 source, let's say I want to have 2 sources that check and "crawl" across this web of blogs, how can I de-duplicate across every part of this process?

Source A and source B both stumble across the same blog to be fetched, they both place this onto the blog-index queue, this is a data race, as it means the workers who fetch these 2 blogs will both see missing post IDs (if the blog has em), and both fire the same duplicate post-fetch request onto the queue.

What I want to do is a distributed task management system, which steps through tasks (and creates subtasks), and get rid of duplicate tasks.

In a message broker, I can (for example) *technically* de-duplicate by using message IDs in rabbitmq, but that doesn't solve the bigger race condition (source B fires a blog-index request that A fired earlier, and the results of that blog-index has resulted in a bunch of post-fetch requests that're still queued).

TL;DR: Sequential Task Management between different message broker queues.

Comment: Have you considered an existing task management system like temporal.io?

Comment: Never heard of it, i'll give it a look